# Tizen studio log missing

Tags: logging, tizen, tizen-studio

I am developing tizen wear application using Tizen studio 2.0. I am having an issue that I can't get any device logs in the device manager log view (screenshot attached). It is always empty. However when I use `sdb dlog` commands I can view the logs. 
I feel that filtering the logs via device manager log UI is easier so I want to see the logs in device manager log view.

Let me know how to get logs in device manager log view.

[image: Tizen device manager logs]

Comment: Any one please please please answer this.

Comment: To generate and view system logs in Tizen Studio, you can use the dlog logging service: link: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/error-handling/system-logs and https://developer.tizen.org/development/tizen-studio/native-tools/debugging-your-app/log-view.

Comment: @Yasinshihab Yes I am using dlog, thats why I can see the logs in 'sdb dlog' in terminal, My issue is that the device manager log view is empty, as in the screenshot.

Comment: Try re-installing Tizen Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this discussion link :

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/native-application-development/log-view-empty-when-using-actual-device-emulator-works-fine?langredirect=1

It was reported as a bug to the developer team.